# Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeExtension::setIsPagebuilderEnabled()

Tags: magento2, deployment, github

I'm using [Mad-IT GitHub Actions](https://github.com/MAD-I-T/magento-actions) to build a magento 2.4.3 store.

When it does the magento install step, I'm getting

> Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeExtension::setIsPagebuilderEnabled()

The action was building successfully.
We've since installed and committed a theme, and now get this error, but I can't work out where it's from, or if there's something missing

Full stack trace:

```
...
Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Enabling caches:
Current status:
layout: 1
block_html: 1
full_page: 1
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4050 in /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler()
#1 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(4050): trigger_error()
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /github/workspace/magento/bin/magento:0
Call to undefined method Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeExtension::setIsPagebuilderEnabled()#0 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\PageBuilder\Plugin\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\RepositoryPlugin->afterGet()
#1 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#2 /github/workspace/magento/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Repository/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#3 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Setup/Patch/Data/SetInitialSearchWeightForAttributes.php(103): Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository\Interceptor->get()
#4 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Setup/Patch/Data/SetInitialSearchWeightForAttributes.php(56): Magento\CatalogSearch\Setup\Patch\Data\SetInitialSearchWeightForAttributes->setWeight()
#5 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchApplier.php(162): Magento\CatalogSearch\Setup\Patch\Data\SetInitialSearchWeightForAttributes->apply()
#6 /github/workspace/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1094): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch()
#7 /github/workspace/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(960): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData()
#8 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
#9 /github/workspace/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(389): call_user_func_array()
#10 /github/workspace/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallCommand.php(231): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install()
#11 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand->execute()
#12 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#13 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#14 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#15 /github/workspace/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#16 /github/workspace/magento/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

Comment: Have you seen this thread yet? https://github.com/davidalger/warden-env-magento2/issues/16 It links to an issue created in the magento/magento2-page-builder github: https://github.com/magento/magento2-page-builder/issues/730 It might give you a little more direction.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone facing this issue, please have look at this hotfix

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/RepositoryPlugin.php     b/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/RepositoryPlugin.php
index c566c4d5c2a..bb7a7f8b860 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/RepositoryPlugin.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-page-builder/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/RepositoryPlugin.php
@@ -36,8 +36,9 @@
     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $subject,
     \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface $attribute
 ) {
-        $isPageBuilderEnabled = $attribute->getData('extension_attributes')
-            ? $attribute->getData('extension_attributes')->getIsPagebuilderEnabled()
+        $extensionAttributes = $attribute->getData('extension_attributes');
+        $isPageBuilderEnabled = $extensionAttributes && method_exists($extensionAttributes, 'getIsPagebuilderEnabled')
+            ? $extensionAttributes->getIsPagebuilderEnabled()
         : 0;
     $attribute->setData('is_pagebuilder_enabled', $isPageBuilderEnabled);
 }
@@ -58,7 +59,10 @@
     $extensionAttribute = $result->getExtensionAttributes()
         ? $result->getExtensionAttributes()
         : $this->extensionAttributesFactory->create();
-        $extensionAttribute->setIsPagebuilderEnabled($isPageBuilderEnabled);
+
+        if (method_exists($extensionAttribute, 'setIsPagebuilderEnabled')) {
+            $extensionAttribute->setIsPagebuilderEnabled($isPageBuilderEnabled);
+        }
     $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttribute);
     return $result;
 }
```

If this patch did not work but command please do it manually

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was my `config.php` was not checked into source control - meaning Github Actions could not find it.

Committing this file to git, made this error go away.